# IBM Cloud Databases for MongoDB: Detailed Monitoring

Tags: mongodb, ibm-cloud, monitoring, grafana, ibm-cloud-monitoring

I use IBM Cloud Databases for MongoDB in one of my projects. This service is integrated with Grafana within IBM. Grafana only lets me monitor two specific metrics: disc usage and RAM usage. I need to monitor way more metrics such as delays. I cannot use the 3rd party apps for detailed MongoDB monitoring because IBM doesn't let me run any apps within its operation system. Is there any possibility for me to monitor more metrics on IBM Cloud Databases for MongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

IBM Support says:
Unfortunately, not at the moment. we only expose the 4 metrics relating to Disk and Ram. We're talking about how to expose more , but that will not happen for a while. I don't have any eta from dev on it.